# Mysql where clause query on json column in which array of objects data

Tags: mysql, json, database, where-clause

I have following records in mysql(5.7) table in which data has json data type.

```
id  data 
1   [{"key": 1,"value": "rom"},{"key": 54,"x": 1}]
2   [{"key": 1,"value": "sun"},{"key": 54,"x": 0.5}]
3   [{"key": 54,"x": 1.2},{"key": 1,"value": "test"}]
4   [{"key": 1,"value": "japan"},{"key": 54,"x": 2}]
5   [{"key": 1,"value": "east"},{"key": 52,"x": 1}]
```

I want to make where condition on data column.
if key = 54 and x >= 1  then it should retrun id => 1,3,4

if key = 54 and x < 1  then it should retrun id => 2

Comment: Are you using MySQL version 8+ ?

Comment: Mysql Version is 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with arrays is a little messy in cases like this. You end up having to do positional things like the follow that, while they do work, are not easy to read or modify. JSON objects are a little more flexible.

```
select id from y where 
(json_contains(doc,"54","$[0].key") or json_contains(doc,'54',"$[1].key")
AND
(json_extract(doc,"$[0].x") >= 1 or json_extract(doc,"$[1].x") >= 1)
);
```